# Generic not narrowing properly

Tags: typescript

In my code here, I want the function's return type to be determined by the value of a property of the argument.

```
type MockSubscriptionInputs =
  | {
      apiVersion: 'ApiV4'
      products: Product[]
      subscriptionItemType: 'addons' | 'items'
    }
  | {
      apiVersion: 'ApiV5'
      products: Product[]
      subscriptionItemType?: never
    }

type Subscription<Version extends ApiVersion> = Version extends 'ApiV4'
  ? V4Subscription
  : V5Subscription

export function mockSubscriptionWithProducts(
  config: MockSubscriptionInputs,
  count = config.products.length
): Subscription<typeof config.apiVersion> {
  return config.apiVersion === 'ApiV5'
    ? mockV5SubscriptionWithProducts(config.products, count)
    : mockV4SubscriptionWithProducts(
        config.products,
        config.subscriptionItemType,
        count
      )
}
```

However the following statements both get errors that appear to say either that they expect the opposite type or that they expect a union of both types.

```
const subscriptionV5: V5Subscription = mockSubscriptionWithProducts(
  { products, apiVersion: 'ApiV5' }, 4
)
```

```
TS2322: Type
{ id: number; shopifySubscriptionContractId: number | null; shopifyPlanLineId: string; shopifyBillingCycleEndAt: string; interval: "every_month" | "every_2_months" | "every_3_months" | ... 4 more ... | "every_42_days"; ... 4 more ...; customer: { ...; }; } | { ...; }
is not assignable to type
{ id: number; shopifySubscriptionContractId: number | null; shopifyPlanLineId: string; shopifyBillingCycleEndAt: string; interval: "every_month" | "every_2_months" | "every_3_months" | ... 4 more ... | "every_42_days"; ... 4 more ...; customer: { ...; }; }
Type '{ box: { addons: ({ description: string; fullDescription?: string | undefined; image: string; meatGroup: string; packSize: string; price: number; sku: string; markupPrice?: string | undefined; } & { ...; } & { ...; })[]; ... 7 more ...; type: "all_beef" | ... 7 more ... | "basic_beef_chicken_pork"; }; ... 4 more ......' is missing the following properties from type '{ id: number; shopifySubscriptionContractId: number | null; shopifyPlanLineId: string; shopifyBillingCycleEndAt: string; interval: "every_month" | "every_2_months" | "every_3_months" | ... 4 more ... | "every_42_days"; ... 4 more ...; customer: { ...; }; }': shopifySubscriptionContractId, shopifyPlanLineId, shopifyBillingCycleEndAt, lines, customer
```

---

```
const subscriptionV4: V4Subscription = mockSubscriptionWithProducts(
  { products, apiVersion: 'ApiV4', subscriptionItemType: 'items' }, 4
)
```

```
TS2719: Type
{ box: { addons: ({ description: string; fullDescription?: string | undefined; image: string; meatGroup: string; packSize: string; price: number; sku: string; markupPrice?: string | undefined; } & { ...; } & { ...; })[]; ... 7 more ...; type: "all_beef" | ... 7 more ... | "basic_beef_chicken_pork"; }; ... 4 more ......
is not assignable to type
{ box: { addons: ({ description: string; fullDescription?: string | undefined; image: string; meatGroup: string; packSize: string; price: number; sku: string; markupPrice?: string | undefined; } & { ...; } & { ...; })[]; ... 7 more ...; type: "all_beef" | ... 7 more ... | "basic_beef_chicken_pork"; }; ... 4 more ......
. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
Property 'box' is missing in type '{ id: number; shopifySubscriptionContractId: number | null; shopifyPlanLineId: string; shopifyBillingCycleEndAt: string; interval: "every_month" | "every_2_months" | "every_3_months" | ... 4 more ... | "every_42_days"; ... 4 more ...; customer: { ...; }; }' but required in type '{ box: { addons: ({ description: string; fullDescription?: string | undefined; image: string; meatGroup: string; packSize: string; price: number; sku: string; markupPrice?: string | undefined; } & { ...; } & { ...; })[]; ... 7 more ...; type: "all_beef" | ... 7 more ... | "basic_beef_chicken_pork"; }; ... 4 more ......'.
```

Comment: Could we get a [MRE]?

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a self-contained [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue (so if `"box"` is important that should probably be in the code) without exhibiting problems you're not having, like undeclared types and values.  Ideally you would remove these and replace them with native TS types and values, but if you can't do that, please provide at least toy definitions of them.  That is, please [clear up the unrelated problems here](https://tsplay.dev/w1aoGw) and copy the result here *as plaintext*.  Good luck!